# Using Espresso 2.0 + Roboelectric in an Android project

Tags: android, gradle, robolectric, android-espresso

I have already a bunch of Roboelectric test. I want to add [Espresso 2.0](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/ReleaseNotes) which is recently introduced.

Roboelectric introduced [deckard-gradle template project](https://github.com/robolectric/deckard-gradle) to solve problem of using Roboelectric and Espresso together. but the solution is for Espresso 1.1 which is deprecated now.

This is part of my build.gradle file in order to use Espresso 2.0 while I have Roboelectric as well following [Espresso 2.0 instruction](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoSetupInstructions):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.13.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'robolectric'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

robolectric {
    include '**/*Test.class'
    exclude '**/espresso/**/*.class'
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'

    androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.11') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    androidTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4') {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```

But I can not run Roboelectric and Espresso test individually. I appreciate for any suggestion.

Addenda:

```
to run roboelectric test : gradlew test
to run espresso: gradlew connectedAndroidTest
```

Comment: I'm not great expert in instrumentation tests. But I think you can run individual test for Espresso even from studio. To do same with Robolectric you should another gradle plugin (I don't use it so can not say for sure)

Answer (score 3):

Try with this android starter project:
https://github.com/freezy/android-seed

It has many [features](https://github.com/freezy/android-seed#features):

- Loads nicely in Android Studio
- Robolectric tests working and debuggable in IDE (for unit testing)
- Espresso tests working and debuggable in IDE (for functional testing)
- Latest Lollipop compat libs ready to use
- Test coverage enabled

Answer (score 1):

I excluded tests to accomplish what you want.

```
sourceSets {
    androidTest {
        java {
            exclude 'com/company/project/**/*Test.java'
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {taskGraph ->
    def testRunTask = project.tasks.getByName 'testDebug'
    testRunTask.include(['**/*Test.class'])
    testRunTask.exclude(['**/espresso/**/*.class','**/integration/**/*.class'])
}
```